# Simple product of configurabile discount issue

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, price, catalog-price-rules

I have the following  situation:

i have  configurable product **X** which has the price let's say 50$.

Now for this product **X** there are 3 simple products associated on the **Size** attribute, let's say **A,B,C** product

Product **A** - has +1$ more then product **X** => total price - 51$

Product **B**- ...2$ more ..=> 52$

Now the problem:

If i set a discount the configurable product has the discounted price ok.

But for the simple products the discount it calculated like this:
The acctual price for the product  **A** = product **X** discounted(50%) + 1$

What I wish for the product **A** price is  to be like this: 51$ discounted price, not 50$(configurabile product discounted) and then add 1$ after this price.

Does anyone know  how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. One option is to install an extension. (Something like Configurable Products Simple Prices) (other extensions almost certainly will exist)